# Hazelcast as drop-in replacement for Memcached

Tags: memcached, hazelcast, spymemcached

Currently, we have an application that works with Memcached using spy-memcached (Java) client. Wanted to introduce Hazelcast for this application. At a very early stages of this integration, I want to use Hazelcast using Memcached protocol.

Starting standalone Hazelcast server `./server.sh`. and trying to connect from app.
Getting error from Hazelcast console

```
INFO: [172.17.42.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Connection [/127.0.0.1:44028] lost. Reason: java.nio.BufferOverflowException[null]
```

Error from spy-memcached

```
2014-07-28 15:51:23.986 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to exception on {QA sa=localhost/127.0.0.1:5701, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: Report-1281-NULL-NULL Cas: 0 Exp: 0 Flags: 1 Data Length: 2796, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}
java.io.IOException: Disconnected unexpected, will reconnect.
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:452)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:380)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:242)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:836)
2014-07-28 15:51:23.987 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=localhost/127.0.0.1:5701, #Rops=1, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: MarginRequirementsReport-1281-NULL-NULL Cas: 0 Exp: 0 Flags: 1 Data Length: 2796, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}, attempt 0.
2014-07-28 15:51:23.987 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: Report-1281-NULL-NULL Cas: 0 Exp: 0 Flags: 1 Data Length: 2796
```

Apparently, `hazelcast.socket.receive.buffer.size` and `hazelcast.socket.send.buffer.size` properties have nothing to do this this.

Please, advise

Comment: What is the size of the key/values?

Comment: @pveentjer Roughly 50 bytes for keys, 8000 bytes - data. But perfectly works with Memcached and even Couchbase. Hazelcast throws exception.

Comment: When did you get this Exception: on connection or when you try to get data?

Comment: Do you asked at [hazelcast forum at Github](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues)? Maybe they are will answer faster.

Comment: @wwarlock will try it there, thanks!

Comment: wondering if you figured this one out

Comment: @user3813256 not yet. asked in hazelcast gh forum https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3182